# How to read data from Kafka topic in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to loop on top of data we will be receiving from kafka topic but the below code seems to be erroring out with a type mismatch

```
def consume[K, V](consumer: KafkaConsumer[K, V], topic: String, timeoutMillis: Long): Unit = {

    logger.info(s"Start to consume from $topic")

    consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJavaCollection)

    Try {
      while (true) {
        val records: ConsumerRecords[K, V] = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis))
        records.iterator().forEachRemaining { record: ConsumerRecord[K, V] =>
          logger.info(s"""
                         |message
                         |  offset=${record.offset}
                         |  partition=${record.partition}
                         |  key=${record.key}
                         |  value=${record.value}
           """.stripMargin)
        }
      }
    } match {
      case Success(_) =>
        logger.info(s"Finish to consume from $topic")
      case Failure(exception) =>
        logger.error(s"Finish to consume from $topic with error", exception)
    }

    consumer.close()
  }
```

> The error which I am getting while running this snippet is below :
> C:\Users\abcde\IdeaProjects\demo\src\main\scala\com\cbe\mem\xerox\KakfaHelper.scala:24:76
> type mismatch;  found   :
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[K,V] => Unit
> required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >:
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[K,V]]
> records.iterator().forEachRemaining { record: ConsumerRecord[K, V] =>

Please let me know how can I run this snippet having said that I would like to thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would convert the polled records into a Scala Iterable and then just iterate through it using `foreach`:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis)).asScala
records.foreach(record =>
          logger.info(s"""
                         |message
                         |  offset=${record.offset}
                         |  partition=${record.partition}
                         |  key=${record.key}
                         |  value=${record.value}
           """.stripMargin)
)
```